# How to get the first character from another command’s “return value”?

Tags: expl3

Trying to find a solution for [How to set kerning in a combination of macros with a fixed character in between](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/542649/how-to-set-kerning-in-a-combination-of-macros-with-a-fixed-character-in-between), I came across a related problem:
when used as a superscript (in a footnote marker), certain characters will be too close to the main character, e.g. in combinations like o and superscript j.

To tackle both problems, I wanted to create a function that returns a kerning value depending on the first character of the marker’s “string value”.

My first attempts were to simply use `\tl_head:n`, then I read [Convert string to token list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/404108/convert-string-to-token-list) – both give the same, yet not the required result.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\DeclareDocumentCommand \aalph {m}
 {
  \IfInteger { #1 }
   {
    \myAlph:n { #1 }
   }{
    \@ifundefined { r@#1 }
     { yyyy }
     {
      \IfInteger { \getrefnumber { #1 } }
       { \myAlph:n { \getrefnumber { #1 } } }
       { zzzz }
     }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \myAlph:n #1
 {
  \int_to_alph:n { #1 }
 }

\DeclareDocumentCommand \alphKern {m}
 {
  \l_alphKern:n { #1 }
 }

\cs_new:Npn \l_alphKern:n #1
 {
  \str_clear_new:N \l_alph_str
  \tl_clear_new:N \l_tmp_tl

  \str_set:Nn \l_alph_str { \aalph { #1 } }

  \tl_set_rescan:Nno \l_tmp_tl { } { \l_alph_str }

  \tl_head:n \l_tmp_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcounter{test}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{test}{1}
>\aalph{\thetest}<>\alphKern{\thetest}< (exp.: >a<>a<)\\

>\aalph{27}<>\alphKern{27}< (exp.: >aa<>a<)\\

>\aalph{53}<>\alphKern{53}< (exp.: >ba<>b<)\\

>\aalph{283}<>\alphKern{283}< (exp.: >jw<>j<)\\

\end{document}
```

The result:

```
>a<>a< (exp.: >a<>a<)
>aa<>aa< (exp.: >aa<>a<)
>ba<>ba< (exp.: >ba<>b<)
>jw<>jw< (exp.: >jw<>j<)
```

I might be overlooking sth. really obvious – any help is appreciated!

(PS: for this one, I am using XeTeX and as the project is nearly done, I cannot change to anything else)

Comment: In your code, when `#1` is `\thetest`, `\str_set:Nn \l_alph_str { \aalph { #1 } }` defines `\l_alph_str` as string `\aalph {\thetest }`, not the "return value" of `\aalph{\thetest}`. For fully expandable macros, you can use latex3 `e`-type expansion to get its expansion result. But unfortunately, the `xstring` macro `\IfInteger` is not fully expandable, hence `\aalph` is not fully expandable.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Thank you for that very valuable hint! I can avoid `\IfInteger` by other means. Could you make an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(continued from question comments)

The key point is that in `\str_set:Nn \l_alph_str { \aalph { #1 } }` you need to ensure `\aalph { #1 }` is fully expandable, then use `\str_set:Ne` to convert the expansion result to string and store it in `\l_alph_str`.

Assume you can avoid `\IfInteger` by other (fully expandable) means, the following example shows an attempt:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
% make \aalph itself expandable
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand \aalph {m}
 {
%  \IfInteger { #1 }
%   {
    \myAlph:n { #1 }
%   }{
%    \@ifundefined { r@#1 }
%     { yyyy }
%     {
%      \IfInteger { \getrefnumber { #1 } }
%       { \myAlph:n { \getrefnumber { #1 } } }
%       { zzzz }
%     }
%   }
 }

% do not use protected version
\cs_new:Npn \myAlph:n #1
 {
  \int_to_alph:n { #1 }
 }

\DeclareDocumentCommand \alphKern {m}
 {
  \l_alphKern:n { #1 }
 }

\cs_new:Npn \l_alphKern:n #1
 {
  \str_clear_new:N \l_alph_str
  \tl_clear_new:N \l_tmp_tl

  % use \str_set:Ne to fully expand its 2nd arg before converting to string
  \str_set:Ne \l_alph_str { \aalph { #1 } }

  \tl_set_rescan:Nno \l_tmp_tl { } { \l_alph_str }

  % here you need arg-spec "N", not "n"
  \tl_head:N \l_tmp_tl
 }

% this defines \str_set:Ne
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_set:Nn {Ne}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcounter{test}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{test}{1}
>\aalph{\thetest}<>\alphKern{\thetest}< (exp.: >a<>a<)\\

>\aalph{27}<>\alphKern{27}< (exp.: >aa<>a<)\\

>\aalph{53}<>\alphKern{53}< (exp.: >ba<>b<)\\

>\aalph{283}<>\alphKern{283}< (exp.: >jw<>j<)\\

\end{document}
```

Notes:

- `xparse` already loads `expl3` so I delete the `\usepacakge{expl3}`. Also, since LaTeX2e 2020/02/02, (a significant portion of) `expl3` is pre-loaded in LaTeX2e format.
- Fully expandable LaTeX3 functions are indicated by a star (⭑) in documentation [`interface3`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf), as documented in the same doc, sec. I.2. But most other packages do not have a per-macro documentation about expandability, hence you need to check by yourself.