# Compare Token List result to a string

Tags: conditionals, expl3, strings, token-lists

I have a command that (beyond my control) evaluate into a token list, and I want to compare it to a given string, I tried to follow [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55600/comparing-latex3-token-list-to-string) answer and create a variant on `\tl_if_eq`:

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\cmp}{mm}
{
    \tl_set:Nn \l_r_tl { #1 }
    \cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_eq:nnTF { o }
    \tl_if_eq:onTF { \l_r_tl } { #2 } { True } { False }
    %% I also tried:
    % \tl_if_eq:onTF { #1 } { #2 } { True } { False }
}
\tl_new:N \l_r_tl

% The actual command I am using retrieve values using `\sys_get_shell`, so I don't have control over it
\NewDocumentCommand{\dummy}{m}{
    \tl_set:Nn \l_d_tl { #1 }
    \l_d_tl
}
\tl_new:N \l_d_tl

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

But seems like this doesn't seem to work if my value is passes through "dummy":

```latex
\begin{document}
\maketitle
    \cmp{test}{test} % True
    \cmp{\dummy{test}}{test} % False
    \dummy{test} % test
\end{document}
```

How can I get it to evaluate to "True" even when I pass on a `tl` from a different command?

Edit: Adding MWE as requested:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{article}

\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\cmp}{mm}
{
    \tl_set:Nn \l_r_tl { #1 }
    \cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_eq:nnTF { o }
    \tl_if_eq:onTF { \l_r_tl } { #2 } { True } { False }
    %% I also tried:
    % \tl_if_eq:onTF { #1 } { #2 } { True } { False }
}
\tl_new:N \l_r_tl

% The actual command I am using retrieve values using `\sys_get_shell`, so I don't have control over it
\NewDocumentCommand{\dummy}{m}{
    \tl_set:Nn \l_d_tl { #1 }
    \l_d_tl
}
\tl_new:N \l_d_tl

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \cmp{test}{test} % True
    \cmp{\dummy{test}}{test} % False
    \dummy{test} % test
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Nice first question, could you edit your code to begin with your `\documentclass{}` and end with `\end{document}`  though please, a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) please. It makes copy and pasting easier when the code can be compiled as-is

Comment: @JamesT added a full working example

Comment: Special case 2 of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/645995/why-cant-i-use-some-macro-inside-the-argument-of-some-other-macro/646000#646000 . That having said , here if you really don't have control over `dummy` then the problem is not solvable. Try to look at the documentation to see if the `dummy` has an alternative command that stores the result into some token list, then read from that token list (for which it's impossible to give a more specific answer without you explaining what the `dummy` is)

Comment: @user202729 Thanks! `\dummy` is a call to `\sys_get_shell:nnN`, which does store the result in a `tl`, I inlined the call and used that variable and now it works!

Comment: you should move `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_eq:nnTF { o }` outside your definition you only need it once not every time